# Getting an error when running an SQL Sum statement in Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am trying to find out the total cost of all items in a certain table of my database, the cost is stored in another table but the product codes provide links so this is not an issue.

However my issue comes when trying to also get Access to display the Product Code and Description of each item.

Here is my code:

```
   SELECT [Product Code], Description, Sum([Purchase Price]) AS Total
    FROM [products/stock] AS p 
     INNER JOIN [Stock Conversion Items] AS s 
     ON p.[Product Code] = s.[Result PC]
   WHERE s.CutID = [Enter your Cut ID here]
   GROUP BY s.SCID;
```

As you can see, I have chosen what data to display, joined the tables, used [Enter your Cut ID here] to get information from the user and then grouped the information by SCID (A key to denote a single case of items).

Here is the error message:

[image: Error message]

Any help would be massively appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Sorry, added the error message afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, if you use an aggregated query, all columns you use without an aggregation function (like SUM, COUNT, etc), must be in your group by clause. It does not have to be the other way around, so you can have column in your group by without using them anywhere else.

```
  SELECT [Product Code], Description, Sum([Purchase Price]) AS Total 
    FROM [products/stock] AS p  
     INNER JOIN [Stock Conversion Items] AS s  
     ON p.[Product Code] = s.[Result PC] 
   WHERE s.CutID = [Enter your Cut ID here] 
   GROUP BY S.SCID, [Product Code], Description;
```

Answer (score 1):

group them by `[Product Code]` and  `Description`

```
   SELECT [Product Code], Description, Sum([Purchase Price]) AS Total
    FROM [products/stock] AS p 
     INNER JOIN [Stock Conversion Items] AS s 
     ON p.[Product Code] = s.[Result PC]
   WHERE s.CutID = [Enter your Cut ID here]
   GROUP BY [Product Code], Description
```

Comment: But this wouldn't create the desired datasheet? I want them to be grouped by the SCID as to allow me to calculate wastage per conversion instance.

Comment: but you also need to add `product code` and `description` as the two columns are included on your `select` clause. can you add also the structure of your tabel

Answer (score 1):

When using an aggregate function, like `SUM`, you will need to `GROUP BY` all of the other selected columns.  So, your `GROUP BY` should be:

```
GROUP BY S.[SCID], [Product Code], Description;
```